# Proper type for an onClick event in React with Flow types

Tags: reactjs, flow-js

I am trying to create a React component that has a property onClick and I am trying to determine the right type signature for the props of the component.

I have tried the following along with various modifications.

```js
type Props = {
  label: string,
  onClick: ?func: (e: SyntheticMouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => 
}
```

What is the proper type to accept for the onClick prop?

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a typescript tag to this, but events are generally voids since they don't have a return `void`